# Importing XLXS in Microsoft SSMS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and having trouble with import XLXS to query (Details as below). My XLXS file is quite large.

I already upgrade 64 bits and try many tips but it does not work.
Does anyone have a simple solution to have the data imported? Many thanks in advance.

[Import XLXS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZiIY.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSLq3.png)

> TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
>
> The operation could not be completed.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)

Comment: *"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)"* The error is telling you the problem there.

Comment: yea, I try to follow many suggested solutions for it, such as: install 64 bits instead 32 etc. Does not work all. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest you did not install the correct drivers them. What version of ACE did you download? Perhaps it was a different version.